# Can not drag/drop items in a multicolumn sortable list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

My problem is very simple.

I have three columns that I want to be able to sort between using jQuery sortable, but for some reason the items won't start dragging. I have searched here on stackoverflow for the answer but I think I'm doing everything correctly.

- I'm setting the min height on the columns
- I've set padding/margins on the sortable items
- I've used the right options for the sortable UI command

I was able to reproduce the problem using jsbin

Can someone take a quick look and tell me what I did wrong?

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/avikos/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wrap your init function inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.column').sortable({
    connectWith: '.column'
  });
});
```

or the shortcut version

```
$(function(){
  $('.column').sortable({
    connectWith: '.column'
  });
});
```

...then it's working fine for me ( http://jsbin.com/avikos/6/edit).

Otherwise the is executed before the referenced DOM elements are rendered and is therefor not binded.